# Accessing javascript native "this" inside of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, scope

How can i access to `this.today` inside of the `Moved` function? It will be called via `jQuery` so the `this` keyword will be overwritten by jQuery to jQuery object or a DOM element.

Here is something similar to what I have:

```
(function(Map) {
    Map.Timeline = {
        today: null,

        Init: function () {
            jQuery("#timeline").mousemove(Map.Timeline.Moved); // or this.Moved
        },

        Moved: function (event) {
            console.log(this);                  // jQuery Object or DOM element
            console.log(this.today);            // fails
            console.log(Map.Timeline.today);    // works fine
        },

        // more code here ...
```

Comment: You mean `this = Map.Timeline`

Comment: @jacktheripper yes, you mean I manually rewrite it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to use a custom context in a callback call

```
jQuery('#timeline').mousemove(jQuery.proxy(Map.Timeline.Moved, this));
```

Comment: +1 finally a nice example on where to use that feared `proxy` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can store this before it is overwritten:

```
(function(Map) {
var myvar = $(this);
Map.Timeline = {
    today: null,


    Init: function () {
        jQuery("#timeline").mousemove(Map.Timeline.Moved); // or this.Moved
    },

    Moved: function (event) {
        console.log(myvar);                  // jQuery Object or DOM element
        console.log(myvar.today);            // fails
        console.log(Map.Timeline.today);    // works fine
    },

    // more code here ...
```

Comment: Your code does not work. You can't `var myvar` in an object like that.

Comment: Actually I don't wanted to store the jQuery `this` ... I wanted to prevent the overwritten of the native `this` keyword. What you doing there is to storing the jQuery object ...